# How to access array with json values using laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I am having a difficulty accessing the array with json values in it. The values came from another table where I have established a relationship with another table. However, I cannot figure out how to access it correctly. Here is my code.

Model relationship between product and inventory.

**Product**

```
 public function inventory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\InventoryRecord\InventoryRecord');
}
```

**Inventory**

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Product\Product','product_id');
}
```

**View**

```
 @foreach($products as $val)

    <?php //$quantity[$i++] = $val->id; ?>

       <tr class="tbl-prod-row">
         <td><input type='checkbox' style='width:30px; height:20px;' class='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' id='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' value="{{ $val->id }}"></td>
         <td style="display:none;">{{ $val->id }}</td>
         <td style="display:none;">{{ $val->category }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->pharmaceutical }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->description }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->type }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->unit }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->price }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->created_at }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->po_status }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->inventory }}</td>

        </tr>

    @endforeach
```

[image]

There is no error shown here but everytime I wanted to access some values in the array by changing the `$val->inventory` to `$val->inventory->quantity`, it return an error.

[image]

Please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That happen because product has many inventory as defined in product model :

```
$this->hasMany('App\InventoryRecord\InventoryRecord');
```

So when you call `$val->inventory` it will return a collection of inventories as described in the error returned in log **Undefined property ../Collection::$quantity** because you're trying to get attribute from collection.

You have to specify the inventory you want to get the quentity from, e.g :

```
$val->inventory->first()->quantity
$val->inventory[0]->quantity
```

Or you could define new method in the model that return the total of product inventory quantities, e.g :

```
public function inventoriesQuantity(){
   $quantite = 0

   foreach($this->inventory as $inventory){
       $quantity += $inventory->quantity;
   }

   return $quantite;
}
```

Then call it instead of `$val->inventory` :

```
<td>{{ $val->inventoriesQuantity() }}</td>
```

**NOTE :** function `inventory()` in product model should be `inventories()` because it will return a collection of inventories.

Hope this helps.